# Form is not calling custom submit function

Tags: forms

From my understanding, and as I've seen it in other examples of code, all I need to do to call a custom submit function is include the `"#submit" => array("myModule_submit");`.

I use a drupal_set_message to post a message on the site so I can know if the myModule_Submit is being called from the form submit button:

```
function myModule_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
  drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['name']);
}
```

When I click on the "Send" button nothing happens, and it seems the page just refreshes.

```
function myModule_form_builder($form, $form_state){
  $form['myModule_message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("Outgoing Message"),
    '#size' => 150,
    '#maxlength' => 150,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t("Type your message"),
  );

  $form['buttons'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t("Send"),
    '#submit' => array('myModule_submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function myModule_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['name']);
}
```

To my understanding `drupal_set_message()` will display a message to the user on the current page somewhere given the parameters. When I put information in the fields and press submit though there are no messages. I have seen other examples on the web that use this method and they say it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try next:

```
function myModule_simple_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form['firstname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    '#type'  => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['lastname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Last name'),
    '#type'  => 'textfield',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => t('Search'),
    '#type'  => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}
function myModule_simple_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['firstname']);
}
```

Any rendered drupal form already have a submit function. Also try: `drupal_set_message($form);` in your hook_from_alter when `$form_id = 'myModule_simple_form'` too see where is default submit function. You can also add a custom submit funtion in array but it is necesary only if you need more than 1 submit function for your form. In all othre cases use just form_id_submit.

Comment: Can I expect the drupal_set_message() to appear on the form page after submit has been pressed or is it displayed elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. After submit before form.  `drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form_state, true).'</pre>');` will give you all $form_state array that is nicely formated.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem in your code was using `'#type'=>'button'` instead of `'#type'=>'submit'`